# test if only 1 radiobutton is selected in a radiogroup component after fireEvent.click in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test that only 1 radiobutton is clicked after fireEvent.click on a radiobutton.

So far I have tried to get all radiobuttons & looking for code to check how to count if only radiobutton is checked.

```
it("should check if only 1 radiobutton was clicked", () => { 
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const { container } = render(
      <React.Fragment>
        <Radiobutton onClick={handleChange} isChecked label="Dummy Radio1" />
        <Radiobutton
          onClick={handleChange}
          isChecked={false}
          label="Dummy Radio2"
        />
        <Radiobutton
          onClick={handleChange}
          isChecked={false}
          label="Dummy Radio3"
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    const dialogContainer = getAllByRole(container, "radio");
    dialogContainer[0].setAttribute("aria-checked", "true");
    dialogContainer.forEach(key => {
      // 
      // Code to check if only 1 radiobutton was clicked
      // 
    });
});
```

My radiobutton.js

```
<div
      className="radiobutton"
      role="radio"
      onClick={onClick}
      onKeyDown={onKeyPress}
      aria-checked={isChecked}
      tabIndex={0}
      value={label}
    >
      <span className="radiobutton__label">{label}</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fireEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#fireevent) and then use `.checked` with a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```
it("should click on text", () => { 
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const { container } = render(<Radiogroup onClick={handleChange} />);
    const dialogContainer = getAllByRole(container, "radio");

    const checkedItemsBeforeClick = dialogContainer.filter(el=>el.checked)
    expect(checkedItems.length).toEqual(0)
    fireEvent.click(dialogContainer[0]);

    const checkedItemsAfterClick = dialogContainer.filter(el=>el.checked)
    expect(checkedItems.length).toEqual(1)
});
```

Update:

As you aren't using `input` elements, you'll need to do something like this:

```
const RadioButtonGroup ()=>{
 const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState('select_1')
 const handleChange = (ev)=>{
     setSelectedId(ev.target.id)
 }
return (
<React.Fragment>
    <Radiobutton id="select_1 onClick={handleChange} isChecked={selectedId==="select_1"} label="Dummy Radio1" />
    <Radiobutton
      onClick={handleChange}
      isChecked={selectedId==="select_2"} 
      label="Dummy Radio2"
    />
    <Radiobutton
      onClick={handleChange}
      isChecked={false}
      label="Dummy Radio3"
      isChecked={selectedId==="select_2"} 
    />
  </React.Fragment>
)
};
```

And make sure you pass the id prop in to your `Radiobutton`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm unable to filter the dialogContainer as my radiobuttons are not of Input type. It's a DIV tag with aria-role="radio". My Radiobutton has the following attributes:
```

<div
      className="radiobutton"
      role="radio"
      onClick={onClick}
      onKeyDown={onKeyPress}
      aria-checked={isChecked}
      tabIndex={0}
      value={label}
    >
      <span className="radiobutton__label">{label}</span>
    </div>

```
So how do i filter the radios which are checked?

Comment: Does the Radiogroup handle the onClick or is there a parent? Either way, you'll need to mount whichever stateful component handles onClick (and updates the aria-checked prop). Then you can just test the actual behaviour of the component - i.e. if a click happens, does the state (and rendering) update as you expect.

Comment: onClick is handled on the radiobutton component but is managed by the parent (Radiogroup) Component. Yes. I'm able to handle onClick on the radiobutton component.

Comment: I have changed my render code in my question. As I was passing radiogroup component instead of Radiobuttons. And my onClick was handled on the radiobutton component.

Comment: I'm confused... what are you trying to actually test? 'should click on text' doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That was just a dummy statement. Have corrected it now. I want to test that after fireEvent.click() only 1 radiobutton should be checked. But since i'm doing it with <div role="radio" aria-checked="false"></div> I'm unable to test it inside the filter function.

Comment: If the checked status is held in the aria-checked attribute and this is manipulated by a component, then the only way to check this is to render the whole component, simulate a click on the element and check if the aria-checked value has updated.

Comment: Can you please assist me with the code. I figured out alot but not getting how to do it.